# Google app invite bundle failed to pass XCode verification

Tags: ios

I have successfully integrated Google sign-in and app-invite into my iOS app, everything works fine, until upload to App Store, such an error showed up:

[image]

Since the info.plist file of Google app invite is in binary format, we cannot do anything about this issue.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `CFBundleExecutable` from info.plist of Google Signin SDK.

Remove key `Executable file` from plist of Google Sign In SDK.

[image]

[image]